# Creating data in loop subject to moving condition

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to create a list of data in a for loop then store this list in a list if it satisfies some condition. My code is

```
R = 10
lam = 1
proc_length = 100
L = 1
#Empty list to store lists
exponential_procs_lists = []

for procs in range(0,R): 
    #Draw exponential random variables
    z_exponential = np.random.exponential(lam,proc_length)
#Sort values to increase
    z_exponential.sort()
#Insert 0 at start of list
    z_dat_r = np.insert(z_exponential,0,0)
    sum = np.sum(np.diff(z_dat_r))
    if sum < 5*L:
        exponential_procs_lists.append(z_dat_r)
```

which will store some of the R lists that satisfies the sum < 5*L condition. My question is, what is the best way to store R lists where the sum of each list is less than 5*L? The lists can be different length but they must satisfy the condition that the sum of the increments is less than 5*L. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: are you saying you have a working solution and you want a 'better' way? Or do you mean your current solution only stores some of the R lists and you want exactly R lists inside your main encompassing list?

Comment: The code works but all the lists are the same length. I'm looking for a way to generate exactly R lists, where the code checks each list for sum < 5*L and then cuts off the rest of the list elements if sum exceeds 5*L.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Okay so based on your comment, I take that you want to generate an exponential_procs_list, inside which every sublist has a sum < 5*L.</strike>

Well, I modified your code to chop the sublists as soon as the sum exceeds 5*L.
Edit : See answer history to see my last answer for the approach above.

Well looking closer, notice you don't actually need the discrete difference array. You're finding the difference array, summing it up and checking whether the sum's < 5L and if it is, you append the original array.
But notice this:
if your array is like so: `[0, 0.00760541, 0.22281415, 0.60476231]`, 
it's difference array would be `[0.00760541 0.21520874 0.38194816]`.
If you add the first x terms of the difference array, you get the x+1th element of the original array. So you really just need to keep elements which are lesser than 5L:

```py
import numpy as np
R = 10
lam = 1
proc_length = 5
L = 1

exponential_procs_lists = []

def chop(nums, target):
    good_list = []
    for num in nums:
        if num >= target:
            break
        good_list.append(num)
    return good_list

for procs in range(0,R):
    z_exponential = np.random.exponential(lam,proc_length)
    z_exponential.sort()
    z_dat_r = np.insert(z_exponential,0,0)
    good_list = chop(z_dat_r, 5*L)
    exponential_procs_lists.append(good_list)
```

You could probably also just do a binary search(for better time complexity) or use a filter lambda, that's up to you.